# Hook save_post_cpt not triggered when custom fields are modified

Tags: posts, customization

Say I have created a custom post type named 'custom_post'. 'custom_post' contains three custom fields which are added using ACF: 'custom_field_a', 'custom_field_b' and 'custom_field_c', where 'custom_field_c' is the concatenated string of 'custom_field_a' and 'custom_field_b'. Each time post type 'custom_post' is updated, I want to recalculate 'custom_field_c'.

I use the following code to achieve this:

```
function calculate_custom_field_c( $post_ID, $post, $update ) { 
    if ($update){
        $custom_field_a  = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'custom_field_a', true );
        $custom_field_b  = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'custom_field_b', true );       
        // concatenate fields
        $custom_field_c = $custom_field_a . ' ' . $custom_field_b;
        // Update custom field c
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'custom_field_c', $custom_field_c ); 
    }
} 
add_action('save_post_custom_post', 'calculate_custom_field_c', 99999, 3);
```

The function is not triggered when I update one of the custom fields of 'custom_post'. Does anyone know how I can trigger my function when a custom field of a custom post type is updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this action worked as you expected it would cause an infinite loop, everytime your field got updated it would trigger an update which would run the function again that updated the field, triggering an update that would run the function again and updating the field in a loop. What are you trying to achieve that requires the updating of a field when another field is saved?

Comment: I run a job board on which users can fill in their job preferences. These preferences are stored as a post in my db. Based on these preferences; I build a concatenated query url which contains all preferences of that specific user.

As an example; I fill in the user preferences as url query parameters and return that string to the user:
https://fiks.nl/stage/?filter_by_radius_check=on&search_radius=50&filter_job_type%5B%5D=meewerkstage&search_education%5B%5D=1018

Each time the user changes his preferences, I need to recalculate the url based on the new input.

Comment: Anyone get any idea how to resolve this issue?